# joining data in postgresql, having trouble

Tags: postgresql, join

I have two tables, both of which have three identifiers that are the same. Lets say this is an investing sheet. Table 1 and 2 both have the funding round (seed,venture,etc.), the funding code (A,B,C,D) and the raised amount for that round/code ($$).

Now table 2 also has the investor name.

So think about the columns in table 2 like

investor_name  Funding_round  Funding_code raised_amount

Where you will see duplicates for everything for investor name, except for when the funding_round changes.

I want the joined table to spit out the funding round, the funding code, the amount raised for that round/code, and the investor. Now since there will be mutilple investors for each round. This is where I get thrown off. I am ok with duplicates in the raised amount for code.

How would I do this?? I'm stuck!

Comment: I guess I should also say all of these tables have columns that include the companies name and what category they are in. For example Facebook is the company name and category is social media.

Comment: Where is it that you are stuck?  Edit your question to include the SQL query that you have so far and describe what it is doing differently from what you want.

Comment: Its showing just one investor per company..

Comment: Full join table2
ON table2.funding_code = table1.funding_code
AND table2.funding_round=table1.funding_round